# Retrieving the Query used for a OleDBCommand

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently using the following VB code to make a query against an Access Database, I would like to know is it possible to obtain what the `SELECT` statement that is being run and send that output to the console.

```
    Dim QuestionConnectionQuery = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Questions.QuestionID FROM Questions WHERE Questions.QuestionDifficulty=[X] AND ( Questions.LastDateRevealed Is Null OR Questions.LastDateRevealed < DateAdd('d',-2,Date() ) AND Questions.LastUsedKey NOT LIKE ""[Y]"" );", QuestionConnection)
    QuestionConnectionQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("X", questionDifficulty.ToString)
    QuestionConnectionQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("Y", strDatabaseKey)
```

Right now when I try to use: `Console.WriteLine("Query: " & QuestionConnectionQuery.ToString)`

I only get this:

```
Loop Question #1
Query: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
```

Comment: Right now, your parameters are not defined correctly, so this query will never succeed. OleDb uses `?` as the parameter placeholder.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Yup just noticed that. I thought it was okay to use `.Parameters.AddWithValue` for Parameterized ueries? Or does OleDB ignore that altogether?

Comment: It can be okay, but in certain situations `AddWithValue` can **really** shoot yourself in the foot from a performance standpoint. Better to just be explicit about your parameter types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version comes down to this:

```
QuestionConnectionQuery.ToString
```

The `QuestionConnectionQuery` object is much more than just the text of your command. It's also the parameters, execution type, a timeout, and a number of other things. If you want the command text, ask for it:

```
QuestionConnectionQuery.CommandText
```

But that's only the first issue here.

---

Right now, your parameters are not defined correctly, so this query will never succeed. OleDb uses `?` as the parameter placeholder. Then the order in which you add the parameters to the collection has to match the order in which the placeholder shows in the query. The code in your question just has `X` and `Y` directly for parameter placeholders. You want to do this:

```
Dim QuestionConnectionQuery AS New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Questions.QuestionID FROM Questions WHERE Questions.QuestionDifficulty= ? AND ( Questions.LastDateRevealed Is Null OR Questions.LastDateRevealed < DateAdd('d',-2, Date() ) AND Questions.LastUsedKey NOT LIKE ? );", QuestionConnection)
QuestionConnectionQuery.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value  = questionDifficulty
QuestionConnectionQuery.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value =  strDatabaseKey
```

I had to guess at the type and lengths of your parameters. Adjust that to match the actual types and lengths of the columns in your database.

Once you have made these fixes, this next thing to understand is that *the completed query **never** exists.*  The whole point of parameterized queries is parameter data is **never** substituted directly into the sql command text, not even by the database engine. This keeps user data separated from the command and prevents any possibility of sql injection attacks.

---

While I'm here, you may also want to examine the WHERE conditions in your query. The WHERE clause currently looks like this:

```
WHERE A AND ( B OR C AND D )
```

Whenever you see an `AND` next to an `OR` like that, within the same parenthetical section, I have to stop and ask if that's what is really intended, or whether you should instead close the parentheses before the final `AND` condition:

```
WHERE A AND (B OR C) AND D
```

Comment: Just to add, do I have to include the length of the `varchar`?

Comment: No, but if you don't ADO may infer an incorrect value, resulting in either truncating something or missing an index.

Comment: I see, well I'll just have to rework the select query abit... The code doesn't seem to do what I want it do and even with the changes suggested, I'm still getting duplicate rows despite me NOT wanting such in my result.

Answer (score 0):

To get or set the text of the command that will be run, use the [`CommandText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtext(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

---

To print the results, you need to actually execute the query. Call its [`ExecuteReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to get an [`OleDbDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use that to iterate over the rows.

```vb
Dim reader = QuestionConnectionQuery.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0))
End While
reader.Close()
```

If you know the data type of the column(s) ahead of time, you can use the type-specific methods like [`GetInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx). If you have multiple columns, change the `0` in this example to the zero-based index of the column you want.

Comment: Sorry I think I see where this came from and have edited my question. I wasn't trying to get the end results of the query... but more like what is the `SELECT`statement that is being run against the database.

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the command text and swap in the parameter values.  It isnt necessarily valid SQL, the NET Provider objects haven't escaped things yet, but you can see what the values are and what the order is for debugging:

```
Function GetFullCommandSQL(cmd As Data.Common.DbCommand) As String

    Dim sql = cmd.CommandText

    For Each p As Data.Common.DbParameter In cmd.Parameters
        If sql.Contains(p.ParameterName) AndAlso p.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If p.Value.GetType Is GetType(String) Then
                sql = sql.Replace(p.ParameterName,
                                  String.Format("'{0}'", p.Value.ToString))
            Else
                sql = sql.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return sql
End Function
```

Given the following SQL:

```
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO Demo (`Name`, StartDate, HP, Active) VALUES (@name, @start, @hp, @act)"
```

After parameters are supplied, you can get back this:

```
INSERT INTO Demo (`Name`, StartDate, HP, Active) VALUES ('johnny', 2/11/2010 12:00:00 AM, 6, True)
```

It would need to be modified to work with OleDB '?' type parameter placeholders.  But it will work if the  DbCommand object was created by an `OleDBCOmmandBuilder`, since it uses "@pN" internally.